# Security mechanism during Apache startup - discussion on various solutions that could be considered

Tags: java, xml, apache, security

I have made a apache and mysql based web application using java as a middle-ware (business logic). The application is all ready to be deployed. this application is designed to be run on a single user windows system with apache and mysql with the business logic residing on the same host.

What I need ?

I need a level of security like when the application (basically apache) starts up or initializes, it should check for a code or a dat file with some values (for eg a value would be hard-coded in to this file and this value is created one time using some hardware id of the system and some specific keys for eg. RSA/DSA public keys). How do I implement this in Apache, Should I create this text or image and store it in my MySQL DB and let apache load it at startup or is there any other way to do it, I would also need a logic which will expire this key at the end of 1 year from the implementation, basically hard-code the system time during implementation and compare this time with teh system time during each initialize..I am not very much aware of the coding part as I am a sys admin by profession, but any advice on this will help me sit with my developers and finding out a solution. Thanks